# Creating tables with existing data source in Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC (using MVC4 and EF5) and I have been following the introductory tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/gett...adding-a-model) to create a model, controller,and the views. I want to create an "Orders" screen where all orders are displayed, etc, just so I can understand CRUD operations with EF but when I publish to the server I am getting an error.

The first thing I did was right-click the models folder and add a new class to create a model:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<Table("Orders")> _
Public Class Orders
    <Key()> _
  <DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)> _
    Public Property OrderID As Integer
    Public Property UserID As Integer
    Public Property OrderDate As DateTime
    Public Property OrderAmount As Decimal
End Class

Public Class OrdersDBContext
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("OrdersDBContext")
    End Sub

    Public OrderList As DbSet(Of Orders)
    Public Property Orders As DbSet(Of Orders)
End Class
```

The next thing I did was add a line item into the Web.Config file:

```
<add name="OrdersDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=dbnumber.db.1and1.com,1433;Initial Catalog=db620663152;User Id=dbo620663152;Password=xxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I built the project, eventually was able to create an "OrdersController" by right-clicking on the controller folder and selecting "Add Controller", making the appropriate selections in the wizard. Controller is now added. When I actually navigate to the newly-added orders area, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1787814
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341674
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +869
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +413
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +163
System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClassa.<DbCreateDatabase>b__7(SqlConnection conn) +33
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +92
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +379
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +276
System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +84
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists() +70
System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +44
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +253
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext) +125
System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(Boolean skipExistsCheck) +115
System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +307
System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__6() +19
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +60
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +181
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c) +7
System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +110
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +185
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +73
System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +28
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +15
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnume rator() +40
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
TampaBayDeliveryV4.OrdersController.Index() +21
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +181
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +58
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +225
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651516
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34280
```

So, I am not really sure whats going on here. I am using a shared host and cannot access the database remotely; I also cannot have the code create a new database, the code needs to use the existing database and add the tables.  This was fine for the account model (it created the necessary underlying tables for authentication/accounts). I think the issue here is that the code expects to create a new database (since the table for orders doesn't exist yet?).

If I am not off-base with my assumption, what should I do to tell my MVC app to use the existing data-source in the connection string rather than try and create a whole new database?  I just basically want my application to create the tables with the given connection string in the web.config file.

Thanks for any advice.